# Android Sencha Touch 1.1 Password field(Two fields show up on field focus)

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I am using the password field component inside form panel which uses vbox layout. In android while onfocus the password field shows extra field on that.I reffered the below link but i can't got a clear idea.
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?125489

Please guide me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

```
{
     xtype:'passwordfield',
     label:'Password',
     id:'ap_pswd',
     name:'ap_pswd_name',
     labelWidth:'150px',
     width:'400px',
     required:true,
     style:'margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;',
     },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the native behaviour of browser, so you can do nothing about this.
The one thing you can do is to hide browser's input element while scrolling.

```
if (document.activeElement && ('blur' in document.activeElement) &&
                (document.activeElement.tagName == 'INPUT' || document.activeElement.tagName == 'TEXTAREA')) {
            document.activeElement.blur();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer CrourVult. It partially fixed my problem.